# Why does my Mac not see my external drive as a boot option unless connected via an Apple-branded dongle

Tags: bootcamp, external-disk

I'm running into this odd issue where my external drive (Windows 10, Bootcamp) will only appear as a boot option if connected via the Apple dongle, and not via my regular off-brand dock/dongle.

Odd thing is, it works even if I connect the drive to the Apple dongle, then to the off-brand dongle, but not if I connect it to the off-brand dongle directly.

I've managed to boot from it (holding Alt/Opt on start), but that was with it connected directly to the Mac with the Apple-branded dongle.

I'm on an MBP 16" 2019

Comment: Which Apple dongle are you referring to?

Comment: https://www.apple.com/sg/shop/product/MUF82ZA/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter

Oh this one, the USB C Digital AV Multiport Adapter

Comment: I might suggest the USB-C port on the Mac provides thunderbolt 3 and USB 3.1, where as the USB-C port on the Apple dongle only provides USB 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does my Mac not see my external drive as a boot option unless connected via an Apple-branded dongle?

**Low quality [USB bridge](https://www.microchip.com/design-centers/usb/usb-hubs-and-devices/products/usb-bridges).**

Inside the dongle, there's an IC (integrated circuit) that bridges the USB bus on your computer with the peripheral device.  Off brand manufacturers look for every edge to increase their profit margin so they use components that aren't exactly up to par.

Personally, I'm very wary of plugging in an off brand, low cost peripheral device into what is the highest priced laptops/desktops on the market today.

There was a time when [USB cables were being made so poorly they could actually kill your device](https://gizmodo.com/cheap-usb-c-cables-could-kill-your-phone-or-laptop-1757115350).  This is why you go with reputable brands.  I'm partial to Anker ([they make an equivalent to the Multi-Port AV Adapter](http://anker-usbc-hub-hdmi-4K-power-delivery)) because they offer an 18 to 24 month warranty on all products.

Comment: If the off-brand dock/dongle is low quality and doesn't support booting, how is it I'm able to boot if I connect the drive to the Apple dongle, then to the off-brand one though? ie.


    [External Drive] -> [Apple USB C AV Adapter] -> [Off-brand Adapter] -> [Mac]

This works

Comment: I'm not understanding your question.  Please expand.

Comment: Also, I'm working with another user having a [similar problem](https://bit.ly/2XojHW6) - 2 brand new, off brand USB external drives cannot be formatted in macOS but can be in Windows.  I know it's just my opinion but I wouldn't risk my data on off branded products.

Comment: Sorry, let me try again

What I meant is that if I connected the drive to the Apple dongle, then connected the Apple dongle to the off-brand dongle, and then the off-brand dongle to the Mac, the Mac would see it as a boot option. But I wouldn't expect that if the off-brand dongle had a low quality USB bridge. If the issue was the off-brand dongle, I'd imagine it wouldn't support booting from the drive at all.

Comment: So `Mac → FooBar Dongle → Apple Dongle → Drive` boots is what you're saying.  Just guessing here, the Apple dongle presents the correct ATA commands to the drive to see it and the no-name dongle simply passes that info through.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm seeing. Is there any way I can tell if it truly is what you've described? That the Apple dongle sends the right ATA commands, but the off-brand one doesn't? 

I'm just trying to understand the situation better so I know what to look for in my next purchase

Comment: Not really.  As an example, it's widely known that [getting SMART status of a USB drive](https://bit.ly/3gsG9WO) is a toss up because of the bridge.  Finding out the bride a manufacturer uses is not reliable and even if you do, staying up to date is next to impossible.  That's why I stick with known good brands (i.e. WD for my drives, PNY, SanDisk, Kingston, etc for SSDs and memory).  Anker, Belkin, IOGear, StarTech are all good brands.  I'm not saying they are perfect, but these guys tend to protect their reputation and build quality products.

Comment: After several years of testing MDP > HDMI adapters, then USBC > HDMI adapters, the clear winners were manufactured by Belkin and Anker. We needed to provide adapters in >100 classrooms and many conference rooms, and these manufacturers produce durable products which withstand a beating while providing superlative performance.